# How to embed a ngrx store in a package based on angular while it can be mounted on the consumer?

Tags: angular, webpack, redux, store, ngrx

As redux pattern has the single truth, if I pack my project using ngrx , how does the consumer mount this store node on his store (if has)? Or how can I expose my store for the consumer to mount?

Comment: Unclear what your question is. Do you mean you have ngrx inside a library nom package?

Comment: @MikeOne yes ,  I want to pack some modules in my project into a npm package.There are some dependancy on ngrx within these modules.I also would like the consumer of this package being able to mount the store into their own store , as a child node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your package you should call `StoreModule.forFeature` and `EffectsModule.forFeature` to provide your reducers and effects.

Then when a user installs your package and imports your module it will work out of the box. The user has to import `StoreModule.forRoot` and `EffectsModule.forRoot` in the same module or in any of its parents.